# TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined at eval react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I am unable to get server response using redux the following code show my axios call

```
axios
    .post("/mailaccounts/emailaccounts/", mailAccount)
    .then((response) => {
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_MAILACCOUNT,
        payload: response.data,
      });
      toastOnSuccess("Added successfully!");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
      toastOnError(error);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      toggleTopLoader(false);
    });
```

the server is throwing 400 bad request errors along with the respective errors as can be seen in the screenshot

[image]

but I am getting the Type Error in Catch of exception.

Comment: How does mailAccount look like?

Comment: I know there is an error, in mailAccount that is missing a required param. but I want to show server-side error.